# How to say "to take in" when in reference to people?

Tags: words, verbs

I'm writing something to an old dorm manager I had - I want to ask if he's still taking in students from a particular school (as dorm residents).  In English, I'd ask "Are you still taking in X school's students?"  How would I translate the "taking in" part of the sentence in Japanese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commonly, we would use:

> 「受{う}け入{い}れる」、「引{ひ}き受ける」、「部屋{へや}を貸{か}す」, etc.

You could say:

> 「まだ（or 現在{げんざい}も）[school name] の学生{がくせい} + **を** + 受け入れておられますか。」
>
> 「今{いま}でも、[school name] の学生 + **に** + 部屋を貸されていますか。」

, etc.

I put those in fairly polite forms to be on the safe side.  I did not use the super-polite forms, thinking that you would have difficulty saying the other things correctly on the same super-polite level.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think the phrasing would translate that directly from English.  Thank you!